# Learning mathematics for econometrics: which books or courses and where to start?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, probability-limit-theorems

I'm currently working on increasingly complicated problems as a PhD student in economics, most of which pertains to econometrics, and I find that my ability to formalize arguments is still wanting. I re-worked nearly all the theorems in an obscure paper weeks ago and it was very instructive, so it appears I can "hack" my way through it to some extent.

However, I would like to acquire a little more ease. To give you an example, consider the proofs in the Appendix of this [paper](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/191548/1/1047196697.pdf) or that [paper](https://academic.oup.com/ectj/article/21/1/C1/5056401#130274261)... I can tediously follow **some** of it, but I can't say I would come up with that kind of thing from scratch.

---

So, what I'd need are some ideas on where I could find material to improve my understanding of the sort of math you see in those papers. Of course, I'm not talking about linear algebra. It's more the issue of obtaining limiting distributions when it takes more than a bit of algebra as it would for, say, ordinary least squares.

Comment: For the high dimension part, strongly recommend van der Vaart and Wellner ``Weak convergence and Empirical Processes'' and Chernozhukov, Chetverikov and Kengo's 2014 annals paper, the gaussian approximation one, both provide very powerful and useful tools.

Comment: @Q9y5 I never studied mathematics formally, but I can use some of it. Those references are bit demanding for me, even though it does seem relevant. My problem, really, is that I can't afford to study math just for the fun of it. I need to know stuff to help me out -- and not waste time on stuff I will not use.

Comment: I used to have the same problem, and so did my classmates. For example, to understand a proof, it uses a theorem from functional analysis, after going back to that part, it has a intersection with topology... Time is limited, the short term goal is to finish phd study in time. My strategy is to go through the proof for the most general case, after that, trust the theorem and use it. Like the maximal inequality in 2014 annals paper, complicated but powerful. I know I have proved it once in my life, after that I just check the parameters plug in the result to get the asymptotic order.

Comment: While it is a good strategy, theorems will often involve concepts I have never seen in their statements. It's sort of the issue -- knowing just enough to be able to work through it doesn't come with an obvious map.